# Apply group by on a particular column and set order of the records in the below given way in oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, group-by, sql-order-by, sequence

Please help me to get output in the below order.

MyCode Sample:

i_claim_id := 'CL0000001010';
i_claim_version  := '0';

**NOTE: Order Number should set as 1 for the input claim's Member.**

```
CURSOR mem_data (i_claimid   claims.claimid%type,
                 i_claimversion  claims.claimversino%type) IS
select Member_id,OrderNumber
from claimdata
where claimid=i_claimid
and claimversion=i_claimversion;

CUrsor findinputclaimmemberid (i_claimid   claims.claimid%type,
                               i_claimversion  claims.claimversino%type) IS
select member_id
from claim
where claimid=i_claimid   
claimversino=i_claimversion;

TYPE Membertable is table of claims.member_id%type index by binary integer;
TYPE Numbertable is table of number index by binary integer;

lv_memberid   Membertable;
lv_number     Numbertable;
lv_inputmemberid   Membertable;

TYPE Memrec IS RECORD (Member_id claims.member_id%type,
                       OrderNumber   Number);

TYPE t_Memrec_tbl IS TABLE of Memrec;
Memrec_tbl    t_Memrec_tbl := t_Memrec_tbl();

ln_index  Number :=1;
ln_total  Number;
ln_primarynumber    Number := 1;
ln_otherMember      Number  := 2;
BEGIN

Memrec_tbl.DELETE;

OPEN mem_data (iclaimid,iclaimversion);
FETCH mem_data INTO lv_memberid, Numbertable ;

ln_total  := mem_data.count;

OPEN findinputclaimmemberid (iclaimid,iclaimversion);
FETCH findinputclaimmemberid  INTO lv_inputmemberid   ;
CLOSE findinputclaimmemberid ;

Loop

Exit When ln_inex >= ln_total  ;
Memrec_tbl.EXTEND;
Memrec_tbl(ln_index).Member_Id := lv_memberid(ln_index);

IF lv_inputmemberid(ln_index) = lv_memberid(ln_index) THEN
   Memrec_tbl(ln_index).OrderNumber  := ln_primarynumber;
   ln_otherMember      := ln_otherMember      - 1;

ELSE

    Memrec_tbl(ln_index).OrderNumber  := ln_otherMember;

END IF;

ln_index   := ln_index   +1;
ln_otherMember      := ln_otherMember      +1;

END Loop;
close mem_data ;

END;
```

**Current Output I am getting the below format:**

```
Member_Id      OrderNumber
Emp00001002       6
Emp00001002       2
Emp00001002       3
Emp00001001       4
Emp00001001       5
Emp00001005       1   **-- Input Claim Id's Member Id**
Emp00001008       7
Emp00001008       8
Emp00001008       9
```

**I want to get output in the below format:**

```
Member_Id      OrderNumber
Emp00001002       2
Emp00001002       2
Emp00001002       2
Emp00001001       3
Emp00001001       3
Emp00001005       1   **-- Input Claim Id's Member Id**
Emp00001008       4
Emp00001008       4
Emp00001008       4
```

Please comment way to get the output in below format.

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `Edit` button just below the tags and include the input data which is producing the output you're getting. Thanks.

Comment: Rather than your trial and corrections, I think you should post your sample data and Expected output. This might help you better.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica .. The input data i should pass "ClaimId- CL00000001010" and ClaimVersion = 0 ". For this input claim member id it will check and find all it family members. For Input claim member the order number should set as 1 and for other members it has set 2 ,3, 4 and so on.  Please refer the expected output format .

Comment: @AnkitBajpai... Sample input and output format i have given.

Comment: When sample data is requested the requestor(s) mean more the just the parameter to your procedure. What is being requested is actual table data. In this case data in the claimdata and claim tables. Either as formatted text or  better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). Please update your question to provide that data.

Comment: It may be beneficial for you to review the help section [ask].